# assigning a non declared value inside an if statement in typescript

Tags: typescript

im trying to do this in typescript

```
// some_array is filled with objects

if (let result = some_array.find(o => o.id == 42)) {
    // do stuff with result
}
```

some_array.find() will return either 'undefined' or an object

as this code is not legit in typescript, is there a way to do this?

Right now I would do this

```
let result = some_array.find(o => o.id == 42)

if (result) {
    // do stuff with result
}
```

i know its just one more line but it would be cleaner and more readable the other way.

Comment: "it would be cleaner and more readable the other way."..why you think so? I cannot agree at all. The second is definitely more readable and standard way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this:

```
let result;
if (result = some_array.find(o => o.id == 42)) {
    console.log(result.x);
}
```

But I don't think that you can have the `let` (or `var`/`const`) decleration in the `if`.